# Will there be no more printed books for macOS Support Essentials Ventura (ACSP exam)? The book series was called "Apple Pro Training Series"

Tags: ios, ventura

I took the Apple Certified Support Professional (ACSP) exam very long time ago. I learned quite a bit, was able to eliminate gaps. However, the exam was not very difficult.

Now I want to take the exam again for the current Ventura release. I saw on the Apple website that a lot of iOS specific topics are represented in the exam. That's where my gaps are and I want to close them.

The industry has gone towards online training, but I prefer a printed book (it's a old habit).

Does Apple no longer print books for the certifications? Or do I just have to wait since Ventura was a relatively fresh release? Does anyone know the current status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple Pro Training Series is now published by Peachpit (part of Pearson).  The most recent is [macOS Support Essentials 12](https://www.peachpit.com/store/macos-support-essentials-12-apple-pro-training-series-9780137696444). Based on the last two years, we might expect the Ventura version in March.

Comment: it's now Tue Apr 4 and there is no book . Any idea ?

Comment: No, sorry. And it is not in the list of upcoming titles.